# How to aggregate two nested arrays for two different outputs of single collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My desired outcome is check common ids and their count between friends. One is closed friends count and another one is normal friends count.

Here data is the list of my friends and user is me.

```
async function uinfo(data, user){
  const arr = []
    for (const i of data) {
      await Profile.aggregate([{"$match": {"_id": {"$in": [user, i._id]}}}, {"$unwind": "$list.closedFriends"}, {"$group": {_id: "$list.closedFriends.id", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {count: 2}}, {$project: {_id: 1}}], function(err, result){
          if(result.length >= 1){
            i.cfcount = result.length
          }
          else{
            i.cfcount = 0
          }
      })
      await Profile.aggregate([{"$match": {"_id": {"$in": [user, i._id]}}}, {"$unwind": "$list.friends"}, {"$group": {_id: "$list.friends.id", count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {count: 2}}, {$project: {_id: 1}}], function(err, result1){
          if(result1.length >= 1){
            i.fcount = result1.length
          }
          else{
            i.fcount = 0
          }
      })
      arr.push(i)
    }
    console.log(arr)
    return await Promise.all(arr)
}
```

By performing two separate queries i am getting proper result but i want to combine these two queries.

One more problem with above one is, output of result1 is not giving promised output for last fetching(or matching).

**Edit:-**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "friends" : [2,3,4], "closedFriends":[5,6,7] }
{ "_id" : 2, "friends" : [ 1,3,5 ], "closedFriends" : [4,6,7] }
```

In the above database the common friends between 1 and 2 is 3 and closedFriends are 6 and 7. The desired output is cfcount is 2 and fcount is 1 along with ids.

**Edit2:-**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "friends" : [{id:1, name:'john', score:0}, {id:2, name:'john', score:0}, {id:3, name:'john', score:0}], "closedFriends":[{id:8, name:'john', score:0}, {id:4, name:'john', score:0}, {id:5, name:'john', score:0}] }
{ "_id" : 2, "friends" : [{id:2, name:'john', score:0}, {id:7, name:'john', score:0}, {id:3, name:'john', score:0} ], "closedFriends" : [{id:1, name:'john', score:0}, {id:9, name:'john', score:0}, {id:8, name:'john', score:0}] }
```

Here along with count I want to include filed 'name' and 'score' in aggregated output.

Comment: It is unclear what is your desired result, and what are the problems you are facing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am finding common friends. But here i have two separate nested arrays for closedFriends and friends so for those two list i want to calculate common friends separately in single aggregation.

Comment: Can you show an example of the result you are seeking for?

Comment: I have edited question, i hope it clarifies the scenario. Check the edit @TechWisdom

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework can replace all your Javascript calculations (your *for* loop counting), and thus eliminate *o(2n)* aggregational computations you did, into only one *o(1)*.

```
function uinfo(data, user){
    let mainUser = db.Profile.findOne({_id: user});
    let userIds = Array.from(data, user => user.id);
    return Profile.aggregate([
    {$match: {'_id': {$in: userIds}}},
    {
        $project: {
            '_id' : 1,
            'fcount': {
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                        mainUser.friends,
                        '$friends',
                    ]
                }
            },
            'cfcount': {
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                        mainUser.closedFriends,
                        '$closedFriends',
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ])
}
```

Comment: What is "_id:1" in project? And i'm using mongoose.

Comment: Thanks @TechWisdom , above one is executing properly, the problem is that I forgot to mention friends and closedFriends arrays are nested objects. So it is giving zero as output. Is there any way to solve that. Nested object structure is  {  "friends" : [
   {
    "id" : ObjectId("5abbc313afafad143a4d4f81"),
    "score" : 0,
    "from" : 1522324372828
   } ] }

Comment: You're welcome @code.mevn. `'_id': 1` means to include the field '_id' in the result set ('_id' field is actually included by default, use 0 to exclude it). For referring to a property of nested objects, simply use: `mainUser.friends._id`, `mainUser.closedFriends._id`, `$friends._id`, `$closedFriends._id`. Did it help you?

Comment: It is giving following error :- "MongoError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null"

Comment: That's because your schema is not consistent. You have some documents without "friends" or "closedFriends" arrays. To solve it use $ifNull to fallback to an empty array like this: `{ $ifNull: [ '$friends', [] ] }`, and: `{ $ifNull: [ '$closedFriends', [] ] }`

Comment: Thank you in advance. Because of your solution at that time it saved my time. Can you do one more favor by answering the Edit:-2.

Comment: Hi @TechWisdom, please answer for the Edit:-2. I am not getting anyway to solve this.